# Can someone explain this line of c++ code using reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, pointers, reinterpret-cast

Consider (1):

```
 uint8_t *pUART = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(0x0800);
```

I know (1) simply changes the pUART pointer to 0x0800, but i'm confused how this way of doing it works.

It would make sense if it was (2):

```
 uint8_t* pUART = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(0x0800);
```

Im confused because the (1) is the same as (3):

```
 uint8_t x = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(0x0800);
```

but the compiler does not accept this. Can someone clear this up for me? Why does (1) work but not (3).

Comment: I don't see the difference between `(1)` and `(2)`, except where you put the space around the `*`. But that space makes no difference.

Comment: (3) tries to assign a uint8_t* to a uint8_t, which are not compatible types for that.

Comment: In (3), you try to assign `uint8_t*` to variable of type `uint8_t`, which can't be done implicitly by the compiler.

Comment: btw when the compiler does refuse to accept some code, it usually does it by telling you an error message. It helps to read this error message, and you should include it in the question

Comment: My brain compiled both (1) and (2) so I spent a good minute looking for the difference. I gave up and looked at the comments.

Comment: To "confuse" you a little more: (4) `uint8_t x = *reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(0x0800);` (note the additional asterisk!). This would *compile* again... Now, however, you are doing something entirely different: You assign to x whichever value the address 0x0800 currently holds...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ is a tokenised language. That means whitespace does not matter, except where necessary to separate tokens.

`uint8_t *pUART` and `uint8_t* pUART` mean exactly the same thing. They are three tokens, namely `uint8_t`, `*`, and `pUART`.

Comment: ... and you even can write `uint8_t * PUART` (note the *two* spaces).

Comment: ... or even with no spaces, `uint8_t*PUART`, if you hate readability.

Comment: Thanks, you've cleared things up for me massively :)

Comment: i am a bit surprised that this question didnt trigger a style war yet. Of course `uint8_t* pUART` is how it **should** be written :P

Comment: @ChrisHowarth To extend the matter a little: `char *p1, c, *p2;`creates both p1 and p2 as pointers whereas c is just an ordinary char. Originating from C, the idea of reading is: "p1 is a variable, If i dereference it, then it is a char" (and in concequence, p1 itself *must be* a pointer).

Comment: @ChrisHowarth C++ people prefer directly considering pointer to char being the type of p1, thus C++ people prefer writing `char* p` whereas in C, `char *p` is more common (consequence of the C++ view is many preferring to declare pointers separately: `char* p1; char* p2;` as the pointer characteristic of the type would not expand to both p1 and p2 as shown initially).

Answer (score 0):

Line (3) doesn't work, as you're trying to assign `uint8_t*` pointer type to just `uint8_t`. The correct variant is your line (1).

However, if you're going with `<cstdint>` you can also use the `uintptr_t` type which  is an unsigned int pointer.